Вопрос про цикл в линукс
cat $* | while read line 
Как понять, до захода в цикл, что это последняя строчка в файле и что на следующем заходе будет обрабатываться второй параметр скрипта?

никак но можно сделать прокси что-то типа: cat $* | proxy(какая-то своя программа) | while read line если я понял правильно задачу, в любом случае место для прокси определяете сами, так как не совсем понятно что имеется в виду под "второй параметр скипта"

а что такое прокси?

ну к примеру у вас две комманды одна передает результат другой, так вот между ними может существовать треться которая принимает от первой и передает второй при этом может даже как-то менять переданное

@DaniilLoban Это называется конвейер.

@0andriy да, точно, не совсем корректно выразился

Вы склеили файлы вместе а потом пытаетесь их расклеить. Вложите два цикла:
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@" ; do
    echo $f
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "| $line"
    done < "$f"
done


$ ./temp.sh Temp.java temp.sh
Temp.java
| import java.util.*;
| import javax.script.*;
| 
| public class Temp {
|     public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
|         ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
|         ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
|         String expression = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); 
|         System.out.println(engine.eval(expression));
|     } 
| }
temp.sh
| #!/bin/bash
| for f in "$@" ; do
|     echo $f
|     while IFS= read -r line; do
|         echo "| $line"
|     done < "$f"
| done



...учитывая, что внутренний цикл не нужен при наличии sed.

@0andriy, код в цикле - пример. Я не знаю насколько сложна обработка строк в оригинальном цикле в вопросе. Возможно, что sed её не вытянет.

Ну это надо постараться. Только, если это какой-нибудь SGML-based (XML, HTML, ...) или YAML.
